# keras flow_from_directory returns 0 images

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition

When I try to use the following snippet of code to try to predict on a batch of images, I get a message saying that no images were found.

My directory structure is as follows. I first have a main directory named dogs_vs_cats in which I have two sub directories train and test containing the respective images and also the notebook which contains this code.

```py
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory='test/',
        target_size=(300, 300),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = False,
        class_mode='binary',
        batch_size=1)

filenames = test_generator.filenames
```

Comment: And also I hope in train and test directories contains two folder with respective images.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually forgot to create the additional 2 sub-directories inside the train and test directories.

Comment: Your welcome :-)